# Confusion about why wrapping labels in a div tag will not work?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I tried to wrap 6 label tags in one div tag and my layout broke? Basically it shows my div tag individually encloses each label when I want the div to enclose all of them, I'm not exactly sure how to explain my problem in great detail but if anyone understands this problem please let me know.

Comment: Well, it would certainly help if you provided the code you have written, that seems to be causing this. A wild guess would be a missing or wrong closing-tag, but without a concrete examle, we would all be guessing from here and to eternity :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div>` element is not valid parent of [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element

> **Permitted parent elements**
>
> Any element that accepts [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content).

Comment: Thanks! That explains a few things